# Error 401.2 with smartcard login for new users with more recent Intermediate certificate

Tags: iis-7.5, smartcard, client-certificates, http-status-code-401, cac

### Summary

HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized
You are not authorized to view this page due to invalid authentication headers.

Some new users to my web site cannot log on due to 401.2 and 401.1 errors. Other new users connect without any issue. Users have the DoD CAC smartcard and they are valid for logging into their workstations. All the certificates point to the same root authority, DOD Root 3, but have different intermediate certificates which are DOD CA 38 to DOD CA 51. Users with intermediate certificates numbered 48 or higher get the 401.2 error and cannot log in.

I assume the problem is the more recent intermediate certificates are not installed or configured correctly. I installed the most recent certs from the cert authority using their tool, InstallRoot.exe. MMC confirmed the intermediate certs are in the Certificates (Local Computer) -> Intermediate Certification Authorities -> Certificates.

The server uses the Axway tool to validate certificates. In the Application Event Log for the attempt, it said "Revocation Status: Good" so I assume my OCSP and its cache are set up correctly.

After every 401.2 error is a 401.1 error. The sc-win32-status for the 401.1 error is -1073741715. Is that number significant?

## The detailed configuration description:

I am using IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2. I set up the web server and the web site to require a smartcard to open the web site. To that end I set up iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication with manyToOneMappings. I set up three new users the same way. Two of three new users cannot log in and get both a  401.2 (sc-status=401 sc-substatus=2 sc-win32-status=5) and a "Can't reach this page" with Error Code: INET_E_DOWNLOAD_FAILURE.

### Error in Client Browser

Users get this on their own workstations and the workstations of people who can log in successfully. For this reason, it cannot be a client browser issue.

> #### Can’t reach this page
>
> • Make sure the web address https://MyWebSite is correct
>   • Search for this site on Bing
>   • Refresh the page
>
> More information   The connection to the website was reset. Error
>   Code: **INET_E_DOWNLOAD_FAILURE**

## IIS Log Entries

Here are the IIS log entries for a successful user, First IP, and a failed user, Second IP. The 500 error for sc-win32-status=64 (the "specified network name is no longer available") is the same for successful and unsuccessful logins.

```
time            c-ip        cs-username s-port  cs-method   sc-status   sc-substatus    sc-win32-status time    cs-uri-stem
1/1/2000 19:32  Second IP               443     GET         401         2               5               1734    /
1/1/2000 19:32  Second IP               443     GET         500         0               64              16      /
1/1/2000 19:31  Second IP               443     GET         401         1               -1073741715     2       /
1/1/2000 19:31  Second IP               443     GET         401         2               5               2011    /
1/1/2000 19:31  Second IP               443     GET         500         0               64              118     /
1/1/2000 19:30  First IP    Server\User 443     GET         200         0               0               17      /HMSLoginController.asp
1/1/2000 19:30  First IP    Server\User 443     POST        302         0               0               4       /EntryBanner.asp
1/1/2000 19:30  First IP    Server\User 443     GET         200         0               0               22      /EntryBanner.asp
1/1/2000 19:30  First IP    Server\User 443     GET         200         0               0               4164    /
1/1/2000 19:30  First IP                443     GET         500         0               64              637     /
```

### Request Trace

Partial trace list of the 402.2 error:

4. -GENERAL_REQUEST_HEADERS 
   Headers Connection: Keep-Alive Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/jxr, */* Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate Accept-Language: en-US Host: X.com User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko DNT: 1
5. -GENERAL_GET_URL_METADATA 
   PhysicalPath
   AccessPerms 617
6. -HANDLER_CHANGED 
   OldHandlerName
   NewHandlerName  StaticFile
   NewHandlerModules   StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule
   NewHandlerScriptProcessor
   NewHandlerType
7. -AUTH_START 
   AuthTypeSupported   2
   AuthTypeSupported   Basic
8. -AUTH_END
9. -AUTH_START 
   AuthTypeSupported   128
   AuthTypeSupported   MapCliCert
10. -AUTH_END
11. -AUTH_START 
    AuthTypeSupported   4
    AuthTypeSupported   NT
12. -AUTH_END
13. -AUTH_START 
    AuthTypeSupported   128
    AuthTypeSupported   MapCliCert
14. -AUTH_REQUEST_AUTH_TYPE 
    RequestAuthType 128
    RequestAuthType CertMap
15. -AUTH_END
16. -AUTH_START 
    AuthTypeSupported   16
    AuthTypeSupported   Digest
17. -AUTH_END
18. -AUTH_START 
    AuthTypeSupported   1
    AuthTypeSupported   Anonymous
19. -AUTH_REQUEST_AUTH_TYPE 
    RequestAuthType 1
    RequestAuthType Anonymous
20. -AUTH_SUCCEEDED 
    AuthType    4
    NTLMUsed    false
    RemoteUserName
    AuthUserName
    TokenImpersonationLevel 2
    AuthType    NT
    TokenImpersonationLevel ImpersonationImpersonate
21. -USER_SET 
    AuthType
    UserName
    SupportsIsInRole    true
22. -AUTH_END
23. -GENERAL_SEND_CUSTOM_ERROR 
    HttpStatus  401
    HttpSubStatus   2
    FileNameOrURL   401.htm
24. -GENERAL_FLUSH_RESPONSE_START
25. -GENERAL_RESPONSE_HEADERS 
    Headers Content-Type: text/html Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5 WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate WWW-Authenticate: NTLM X-Powered-By: ASP.NET

### Configuration

I confirmed that the server has all the latest certs using a program distributed by the entity that made our root certificate. I tested the client certificates against the CRL and the server's OCSD call.

#### IIS Server Config

Authentication: Only Active Directory Client Certificate Authentication is enabled - others disabled
Authorization Rules: Deny Anonymous Users - only entry

#### Site Config

Authentication: Anonymous Authentication is enabled and Windows Authentication is enabled
Authorization Rules: Allow webUsers (a Local Server User Group) - only entry
Configuration Editor: system.webServer/security/authentication/iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication
defaultLogonDomain
enabled True
LogonMethod ClearText
manyToOneCertificateMappingsEnabled True
manyToOneMappinqs (Count=19)
oneToOneCertificateMappingsEnabled False
oneToOneMappings (Count=0)

#### Users

Each user set up in the manyToOneMappinqs has a corresponding local server user account. The local user accounts are all in the webUsers group which has permissions to the website. Each user has two mapping rules: Issuer ("O") which is the entity that created the smartcards and Subject ("CN") which is unique to each user.

The list of users is split between two files: the web site's web.config file and the server's applicationhost.config file. The combined users make up the list in the Site's configuration editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## It was a change in the users' certificates!

The smartcard authority is rolling out a change to how the cards will be used to log into websites. There added a brand-new certificate to the card and will deprecate the certificate currently enabled for logging in. Previously we told the users to log in with their email certificate because that was the one that I put into the IIS when we used one-to-one mapping. Also, it's in their signed email so it's easy to get. However that email cert will no longer work for logging in. I used the new cert instead and the new people started working.

The document explaining this claimed that the old old way would still work until next year. Argh! They made me an early adopter.